# Can creatures teleport through Prismatic effects?

Tags: spells, pathfinder-1e, teleportation

Can you and/or your enemies use teleportation effects ([Dimension Door](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/d/dimension-door/), [(Greater) Teleport](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/t/teleport/)) to travel past Prismatic spells?

Does it matter if the spell is [Prismatic Wall](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/p/prismatic-wall) or [Prismatic Sphere](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/p/prismatic-sphere/)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Yes, this works.

*Dimension Door* and *(Greater) Teleport* work a bit differently, but there is nothing preventing their use to travel around *Prismatic Wall* or *Sphere*.

*Dimension Door* says:

> You always arrive at exactly the spot desired – whether by simply visualizing the area or by stating direction.

*(Greater) Teleport* says:

> This spell instantly transports you to a designated destination, which may be as distant as 100 miles per caster level.<sup>1</sup>

Neither of these spells would require you to interact with the Prismatic obstruction in any way.

---

<sup>1</sup> (Greater) Teleport actually says: "This spell functions like teleport, except that there is no range limit".

Answer (score 1):

My reasoning when writing https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/176662/21179 was that *dimension door* is a form of planar travel. *Prismatic wall* says many things but it does not say that it extends into other planes or blocks planar travel.

This admittedly-unofficial reddit link: https://amp.reddit.com/r/Pathfinder_RPG/comments/7cf9o4/can_you_dimension_door_or_teleport_through_a/ agrees with the above, and also adds:

> The effect of teleport, dimension door et al. happens at the caster, not the destination. To identify what a spell "goes through", you need to know where the line of effect is being drawn.

and teleportation effects have "target:you" so they don't send line of effect through the wall.

Comment: Cf. the spell [*forbiddance*](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/f/forbiddance/) that actually wards an area against planar travel (including effects from the teleportation subschool). And perhaps contrast with [*dimensional anchor*](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/d/dimensional-anchor/) that prevents a creature from using planar travel?

Answer (score 0):

#### No. This does not work.

One cannot use a spell to pass through the Indigo nor Violet colours.

[Prismatic Sphere](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/p/prismatic-sphere) says (emphasis added)

> When you’re inside it, however, the sphere blocks any attempt to project something through the sphere (including spells). Other creatures that attempt to attack you **or pass through** suffer the effects of each color, one at a time.

Here, "pass through" makes no distinction between walking through, flying through,  or using a form of planar travel to pass through.

What *specifically* blocks instantaneous travel provided by spells? Both the Indigo color and  Violet color in the wall, as identified in [Prismatic Wall](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/p/prismatic-wall/):

```
Order| Color  | Effect of Color                                  | Negated by
-----+--------+--------------------------------------------------+----------
 6th | Indigo | Stops all spells                                 | Daylight 
     |        | Will save or become insane (as insanity spell).  |  
 7th | Violet | Energy field destroys _all objects and effects_.*| Dispel magic 
     |        | Creatures sent to another plane (Will negates).  |  or Greater Dispel Magic
```

When a spellcaster tries to use [Dimension Door](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/d/dimension-door/) or [Teleport](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/t/teleport/) to enter a fresh Prismatic Sphere containing all colours, he or she will hit the Indigo color. This stops all spells. [Dimension Door](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/d/dimension-door/) is a spell. So is [Teleport](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/t/teleport/). Stopped. The only exception, the only spell not blocked by the Indigo color, is the spell [Daylight](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/d/daylight/).

Even after the Indigo color is taken down, there is the Violet color. The spellcaster has a chance to save or is sent to another plane.  When I have run high level campaigns, "all objects and effects" includes [Dimension Door](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/d/dimension-door/) and [Teleport](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/t/teleport/) effects. The "Creatures sent to another plane" effect is enough for this GM to make a case that the wizards who created Prismatic Sphere thought to block planar travel and instantaneous travel.

Having said all this, one of the best sessions my table had was when one of my players said, "My 18th level Monk is walking through all the colours of that [Prismatic Sphere](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/p/prismatic-sphere)!", made all his saves, took the half damage where stated, then proceeded to introduce the caster to a Flurry of Blows.

---

Comment: It's not clear to me how you are interacting with the indigo wall when dimension dooring.

Comment: It seems like this question imagines a teleporting caster instantaneously traveling in a straight line from his position to the destination. That's a valid house rule—I could get behind that, honestly—, but, traditionally, neither spell nor caster needs to to pass through the layers—[teleportation subschool spells](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/Magic/#Conjuration) take the caster to the Astral Plane then dump the caster out of the Astral Plane at the destination. Without such a house rule, the caster never encounters the layers as they don't extend to the Astral Plane.